# iOS: How to debug UI lag [iPad2 dual-core]

Tags: ios, multithreading

In my App I have to deal with lot of data coming from network and parse it into optimized local format and then save them to DB or send them to UI if any UI is waiting for that data.

I know that doing heavy parsing work in the main thread is stupid because it's going to block the main thread and make the UI interaction quite jumpy.

So here is what I've tried to make sure that UI thread is free:

- Global optimization to remove really slow code despite what thread it is in.
- Lower all thread priorities, ie,

  ```
  NSOperation.threadPriority=0.1;
  NSThread.threadPriority=0.1;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(PRIORITY_LOW));
  ```

After these two steps, UI is much more smooth when some heavy work is being done in background threads, but **still quite jumpy**.

The bug looks like this: While I'm scrolling a table quite fluently and suddenly the table freeze for about 0.1s and then go on as smooth as usual.
During the freeze I can see a CPU burst in Instruments. But in the separate thread view I can see that main thread is OK with almost no CPU consumption.

1. So why does the UI table still freeze?
2. And why do background threads
   still taking so much CPU cycles with such low thread priorities set?
3. **How do you guys make sure that UI is always responsive?**
4. Is there any useful tools to highlight the spots that cause UI freeze?

Comment: The best way is to do something like the twitter app does. there are implementations which can help you on this.[http://blog.leahculver.com/2010/07/iphone-pull-to-refresh.html]

Comment: @Ashishail Thanks for the comment. While pull to refresh is a good way to  minimize the traffic it's not suitable for my App because It need to work offline.

Comment: ohh ok i thought u said ur fetching from network, for local there are lots of things you can do. check that ur cellforrowatindexpath is returning as fast as possible. use prefilled arrays if ur records are in hundreds its fine. if in thousands you can prefetch it based on last row called. so for eg first get 100 rows, when 50th row is called get 100 more, n so on.

Comment: @Ashishail Thank you!It works! And I've learn a skill to remove all potential sync call(like dispatch_sync) in the main thread especially for scrollViewDidScroll and cellForRowAtIndexPath. The result is that the scrolling is much more smooth than before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good solution for this is to use [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) (GCD) and [Objective-C blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) in conjunction with a local cache. When your table-cell loads you should return as quickly as possible from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with the table-cell set up with any locally held data already. Any parts of the cell that need to download data or do any heavy processing should have a place-holder instead (for example an activity indicator). The heavy processing or downloading will happen on another thread like this:

```
// ...This code is at the end of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: where cell
// is already set up and you should have access to your cache and your data
// manager object that will do the processing or downloading for you.

// Show the placeholder (it will hide when real data is set)
cell.placeholder.hidden = NO;
// Check if item is local
MyDataItem* item = [myCache objectForKey:itemKey];
if(item != nil)
{
    // Item is available locally, set up the cell now
    cell.someImageView.image = item.image;
    cell.someLabel.text = item.text;
    cell.placeholder.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    // Item is not in cache, go and get it ready
    [myDataManager goAndGet:itemKey completion:^(MyDataItem* theItem)
    {
        // Put the item in the cache
        [myCache setObject:theItem forKey:itemKey];
        // This block will be executed later and the cell may have been reused
        // by then, so we need to ask the table view directly for the cell.
        // This returns nil if cell is not currently visible.
        MyTableCell* theCell = (MyTableCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Set up the table cell
        if(theCell != nil)
        {
            myCell.someImageView.image = theItem.image;
            myCell.someLabel.text = theItem.text;
            myCell.placeholder.hidden = YES;
        }
    }];
}
return cell;
```

As you can see from the code above, the cell is returned very quickly even when some heavy processing is needed. This keeps the UI nice and responsive without any delays that cause jerky scrolling on the table view. The data manager will use GCD to execute the processing, something like this:

```
- (void)goAndGet:(NSString*)itemKey completion:(void (^)(MyDataItem* theItem))completionBlock
{
    // Note: this uses DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT - but you might want to use
    // a different queue, probably one you created yourself for these tasks.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
    {
        // Do heavy processing or downloading here
        MyDataItem* item = [heavyProcessor doProcessingForItem:itemKey];

        // The completion block must happen on the main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
        {
            // Call the completion block
            completionBlock(item);
        });
    });
}
```

Note that all the code above assumes you're using [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) :)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I checked the answer so late. Yes, I finally use similar solution as yours. I implement background rendering and the scrolling is very smooth now :)

Comment: No problem - I hope it was a useful answer for you. Even if you have it working using a different way, I really recommend reading about Blocks and GCD (see the links at the top of this answer). GCD makes it very easy to perform background tasks that need to run on another thread but call back on the main thread, and also blocks really help to hold temporary references to the objects you need to manipulate later. See how simple the code above is :)

Comment: Yes, I implemented background rendering using GCD, it's very convient to  use and I almost end up with the same pattern as your answer, thank you for you useful answer!